# Splitting small dataset into Training, Validation and Prediction

Tags: dataset, prediction, validation

I have 70 observations in my data. Therefore I believe I can afford to reserve very few observations for validation or for test prediction. Is it suitable to have only 5 observations in my validation data set, and 1 for test prediction?  My proposed sample sizes would be,

Training= 64, Validation=5, Prediction=1.

Is it ok?

Comment: I think the resulting data subgroups would be few in order to give a reasonable validation. You could do a leave one out cross-validation or other cross-validation techinques

Comment: there is no other method other than cross-validate?

Comment: You could split your data in a more balanced way, such as training 40, validation 30 and prediction 10

Comment: owh..  is there any reference towards splitting shirt data in the way you mean.. 40 30 and 10?

Comment: No, it was only a suggestion since I think it's difficult to asses the predictive value of a model by splitting in too low group set. Maybe I don't fully understand your original problem?

Comment: If my edits do not clarify, feel free to change back.  Also:  are these time series data?

Comment: @rolando2. Thank You. No it is not time series data. It is multivariate data, that is why the data is short.

Comment: OK, i've accordingly removed the "forecasting" tag.  Cheers ~

Comment: You wrote, "there is no other method other than cross-validate?" but what you propose is a type of cross-validation.  It's just that there are many ways to achieve that, as @GGA advises.

Comment: What type cross validate is that rolando.. I also did not notice.